# SQL: Finding totals from a joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, so I have two tables in MySQL, `photos` and `views`. Each time a photo is viewed, a new row is created in `views`.

I want the SQL to return a list of photos, with a total number of views for each photo.

I've been trying this query, but its only giving me 1 photo as a result.

```
select photos.id, photos.loc, count(views.id) as views
from photos
left outer join views on views.id=photos.id
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I am surprised you don't need a `GROUP BY`... And that your query is giving results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `count` the views and `group by` the photo:

```
SELECT          photos.id, photos.loc, COUNT(*) AS total_views
FROM            photos
LEFT OUTER JOIN views ON views.id = photos.id
GROUP BY        photos.id, photos.loc
```

Comment: I am not sure if alias-name = table-name (views) is a good idea.

Comment: @JA copy-pasted from OP - but you're right, fixed it to something less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this

```
SELECT
    photos.id,
    photos.loc,
    count(views.id) as viewCount
FROM
    photos,
    LEFT JOIN views ON views.id = photos.id  (Not sure if it should be views.id or views.pid or something)
GROUP BY
    photos.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT photos.id,photos.loc,count(views.id) as views
FROM photos
LEFT JOIN  views 
ON
views.id=photos.id
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(photos.id,photos.loc),())
```